# Type {} is not assignable to type CSSProperties error

Tags: css, typescript

How can I assign inline CSS to an element?
I get an error if I write this, the error is:

> Type '{ backgroundColor: string; color: string; marginRight: number;
> borderRadius: number; borderRight: number; borderLeft: number;
> borderTop: number; borderBottom: string | false; }' is not assignable
> to type 'CSSProperties'.   Types of property 'borderBottom' are
> incompatible.     Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type
> 'string | number | (string & {}) | undefined'.       Type 'false' is
> not assignable to type 'string | number | (string & {}) | undefined'.

```
<span style={{backgroundColor:backgroundColor,color:color,marginRight:3,borderRadius:4,borderRight:0,borderLeft:0,borderTop:0,borderBottom: isCurrent && '3px solid #00416d'}}>{Symbol}</span>
```

Comment: You should use ternary operator like this ```borderBottom: isCurrent ? '3px solid &#00416d' : undefined```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your error says `Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'string | number | (string & {}) | undefined'.`

This is because the expression: `{ ... borderBottom: isCurrent && '3px solid #00416d'` gives `string` if `isCurrent`, otherwise gives `false`.

You should use something like `isCurrent ? '3px solid #00416d' : 0` for `borderBottom` prop, which gives either `string` or `number`, both acceptable for `CSSProperties`.

Full example:

```
<span style={{
  backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
  color: color,
    marginRight: 3,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderRight: 0,
    borderLeft: 0,
    borderTop: 0,
    borderBottom: isCurrent ? '3px solid #00416d' : 0
}}>{Symbol}</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the type-checking, and you actually cannot assign a falsy value to the borderBottom property, which expects a string instead.

You can solve it easily, though:

```
<span style={{ 
  backgroundColor:backgroundColor, 
  color:color,
  marginRight:3,borderRadius:4,
  borderRight:0,
  borderLeft:0,
  borderTop:0,
  borderBottom: isCurrent ? '3px solid #00416d': 'initial'
}}>
  {Symbol}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem of using a ternary operator is that you will need to define a fallback value, here is a simple trick to conditionally add a property to a JSON:

```
<span style={{ 
  backgroundColor:backgroundColor, 
  color:color,
  marginRight:3,borderRadius:4,
  borderRight:0,
  borderLeft:0,
  borderTop:0,
  ...(isCurrent && {borderBottom: '3px solid #00416d'})
}}>
  {Symbol}
</span>
```